# EventEmitter not resolved on iOS if used in external module

Tags: react-native

So, I've been spending quite some time on this issue without success :( Time to turn to the SO community ;)

Here is the situation :
I am working on a react-native module that makes use of the [EventEmitter.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/23331df5a40ad8ddff58f561af24d7401b62e330/Libraries/EventEmitter/EventEmitter.js) class from react-native.

I am facing an issue when using this module from a react-native application. When I import the module in let's say the root `index.ios.js` and launch the app, I get the red screen saying that it is `Unable to resolve module EventEmitter`.

What is strange is that in onny happens on iOS, not Android, and only if the require is done from the "external" module. If done directly from the `index.ios.js` of the react-native app itself, then there is no issue, it correctly finds EventEmitter.

To make it clearer ...

If I create a new react-native app from scratch through `react-native init` and then in the `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` just add the line

`const EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');`

Then it's fine for both iOS and Android, I am able to run the app and create bundles.

However if I put this same line in an external node/npm module that I then import in my `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js`, when I run the app again, it will fail for ios but work for android. Creating bundle show same problem where it fails to build the iOS bundle but succeed to create the Android one.

There is something that I don't understand here. Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Would you not need to add react native as a dependancy for the node module that you are creating? Then add `import {EventEmitter} from 'react-native'` to that module

Comment: Thanks for your comment @13Leprechauns.Already tried that, and does not work :( That's not the way to do it for this module anyway (if you search for EventEmitter in react-native repo you'll find that all imports of it are using the aforementioned syntax. Really don't know the issue. What surprise me is that it is platform dependent. Anyway, ended up switching to `events` third party module which has a similar implementation (based on node own EventEmitter) instead of relying on react-native one. Fixes my problem. Keeping question open though as I'd be interested to know what's going on !